# About Java Android BASE64 decoding to ASCII String

Tags: java, android, arrays, string, base64

I have Base64 string data that i have received from a service.
I am able to decode this data and get byte array.
But when i create a new string from that byte array, my server is not being able to read that data properly.
But this same process in C language of Linux based device is working fine on my server side. That is to say, if i (Base64) decode that same string (using OpenSSL and get char array) on that device and send it to my server, the server is able to read that properly.
Now, i tried a sample code in eclipse to understand the problem. Below is the sample,

```
String base1 = 
"sUqVKrgErEId6j3rH8BMMpzvXuTf05rj0PlO/eLOoJwQb3rXrsplAl28unkZP0WvrXRTlpAmT3Y
ohtPFl2+zyUaCSrYfug5JtVHLoVsJ9++Afpx6A5dupn3KJQ9L9ItfWvatIlamQyMo2S5nDypCw79
B2HNAR/PG1wfgYG5OPMNjNSC801kQSE9ljMg3hH6nrRJhXvEVFlllKIOXOYuR/NORAH9k5W+rQeQ
7ONsnao2zvYjfiKO6eGleL6/DF3MKCnGx1sbci9488EQhEBBOG5FGJ7KjTPEQzn/rq3m1Yj9Le/r
KsmzbRNcJN2p/wy1xz9oHy8jWDm81iwRYndJYAQ==";

byte[] b3 = Base64.getDecoder().decode(base1.getBytes());
System.out.println("B3Len:" + b3.length );

String s2 = new String(b3);
System.out.println("S2Len:" + s2.length() );
System.out.println("B3Hex: " + bytesToHex(b3) );
System.out.println("B3HexLen: " + bytesToHex(b3).length() );

byte[] b2 = s2.getBytes();
System.out.println("B2Len:" + b2.length );
int count = 0;
for(int i = 0; i< b3.length; i++) {
     if(b3[i] != b2[i]) {
         count++;
         System.out.println("Byte: " + i + " >> " + b3[i] + " != " + b2[i]);
     }
 }
System.out.println("Count: " + count);
System.out.println("B2Hex: " + bytesToHex(b2) );
System.out.println("B2HexLen: " + bytesToHex(b2).length() );
```

Below is output:

```
B3Len:256
S2Len:256
B3Hex: 
b14a952ab804ac421dea3deb1fc04c329cef5ee4dfd39ae3d0f94efde2cea09c106f7ad7aeca
65025dbcba79193f45afad74539690264f762886d3c5976fb3c946824ab61fba0e49b551cba1
5b09f7ef807e9c7a03976ea67dca250f4bf48b5f5af6ad2256a6432328d92e670f2a42c3bf41
d8734047f3c6d707e0606e4e3cc3633520bcd35910484f658cc837847ea7ad12615ef1151659
65288397398b91fcd391007f64e56fab41e43b38db276a8db3bd88df88a3ba78695e2fafc317
730a0a71b1d6c6dc8bde3cf0442110104e1b914627b2a34cf110ce7febab79b5623f4b7bfaca
b26cdb44d709376a7fc32d71cfda07cbc8d60e6f358b04589dd25801
B3HexLen: 512
B2Len:256
Byte: 52 >> -112 != 63
Byte: 175 >> -115 != 63
Byte: 252 >> -99 != 63
Count: 3
B2Hex: 
b14a952ab804ac421dea3deb1fc04c329cef5ee4dfd39ae3d0f94efde2cea09c106f7ad7aeca
65025dbcba79193f45afad7453963f264f762886d3c5976fb3c946824ab61fba0e49b551cba1
5b09f7ef807e9c7a03976ea67dca250f4bf48b5f5af6ad2256a6432328d92e670f2a42c3bf41
d8734047f3c6d707e0606e4e3cc3633520bcd35910484f658cc837847ea7ad12615ef1151659
65288397398b91fcd391007f64e56fab41e43b38db276a3fb3bd88df88a3ba78695e2fafc317
730a0a71b1d6c6dc8bde3cf0442110104e1b914627b2a34cf110ce7febab79b5623f4b7bfaca
b26cdb44d709376a7fc32d71cfda07cbc8d60e6f358b04583fd25801
B2HexLen: 512
```

I understand that there are extended characters in this string.
So, here we can see that the reconverting the hex to string is not working properly, because of the differences in the byte arrays.
I actually need this to work because, i have much larger Base64 string than the one in this sample that i need to send to my server which is trying to read ASCII string.

Or,

Can anyone give me a solution that can give me an ASCII String output that is identical to char array output from C language (OpenSSL decoding) on Linux device.

Comment: Well what encoding is your text in? You're currently using the system default encoding, but we don't know what you *should* be using. Is it definitely actually text? Perhaps you should just keep it as a byte array. (It's not clear what you're actually trying to do with the data.)

Comment: If your server expects an ASCII string then that data won’t work. What exactly is it expecting and why do you need to make it into a String? I feel an XY problem here...

Comment: The Base64 strings that i have mentioned in my question maybe not complete text data. Those are obtained from an internal service of the devices that i need to develop the app for. I cannot guarantee the encoding of Base64, i do not know what the 'service' developer has used to develop the internal service. But i tried the above example with UTF-8 and got same results that i have posted here. I definitely know that i need an ASCII output string to send it to my server.